# Do effects that say "from your graveyard to the battlefield" count if the card is cast?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

As an example, [Flayer of the Hatebound](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Flayer%20of%20the%20Hatebound) has, "Whenever Flayer of the Hatebound or another creature enters the battlefield from your graveyard, that creature deals damage equal to its power to any target."
I recently heard that when you specifically cast a creature from the graveyard it goes from graveyard > stack > battlefield and would not trigger Flayer of the Hatebound.
Is this true?
It seems like a very specific and niche ruling.

Comment: Although they do sound very similar, there are lots of differences between the two situations. For example, if a creature "enters play from your graveyard", you don't get the opportunity to pay any optional kicker costs, or the like; if you *cast* it from your graveyard, then you do. It turns out not to be so niche: there is quite a fundamental distinction in Magic between "casting" a card, and having that card enter play because of some other effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is true that abilities like the one you mention will not trigger if a creature is cast from the graveyard. In fact, that is stated in one of Flayer of the Hatebound's Gatherer rulings:

> If you cast a creature card from your graveyard, that card will be put on the stack before entering the battlefield. Flayer of the Hatebound won't trigger.

This is a simple consequence of the facts of the situation. Flayer of the Hatebound's ability specifically triggers when a creature "enters the battlefield from your graveyard". If you cast a creature from your graveyard, it enters the stack from your graveyard and then it enters the battlefield from the stack. Neither of those match the trigger condition so the ability does not trigger.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the stack is a zone like any other, not just some limbo that could be ignored when we consider an object's zone change history.

Comment: There is a similar subtlety with with Living End, IIRC.